# Open source equivelants to wsdl.exe? (how to autogen a web reference proxy class)

Tags: c#, python, ruby-on-rails, web-services

As an ASP.NET developer, I'm used to working with how VS/C# transparently autogens proxy classes for web references via wsdl.exe (yes, I know, we're spoiled), but now that I'm creating documentation for more than one coding platform I'm trying to discover what the equivelant to that is in any other framework.

So is there a similar way to work transparently with web reference proxy classes for say, RoR, PHP, and Python?

And if there's nothing integrated, are there tools you recommend to autogen the proxy classes, or do you recommend to roll custom classes?

Comment: I believe VS uses the wsdl.exe tool to achieve this.  It might help to add a reference to that tool in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had (limited) success with ZSI http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/ for Python.  Try at your own risk.

If it would be possible to run IronPython or IronRuby I would check that out.

I definitely know how VS can spoil you.

Comment: best I was able to find. I'll have to put making an open source wsdl.exe alternative on my to-do list. Thanks!